# importing matplotlib draggable lines module to PyQt5

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, draggable

i am trying  to apply draggable line class to pyqt5  file with multiple subplots figure, it is showing the requried lines but not responding to events from draggable line class,
Drag file

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class draggable_lines:
    def __init__(self, ax, kind, X1,X2,Y1, Y2):
        self.ax = ax
        self.canvas = ax.get_figure().canvas
        self.o = kind
        self.X1 = X1
        self.X2 = X2
        self.Y1 = Y1
        self.Y2 = Y2
        if kind == "h":
            x = [X1, X2]
            y = [Y1,Y2]
        elif kind == "v":
            x = [X1, X2]
            y = [Y1,Y1]
        self.line = lines.Line2D(x, y, picker=5)
        self.ax.add_line(self.line)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
        self.sid = self.canvas.mpl_connect('pick_event', self.clickonline)
    def clickonline(self, event):
        if event.artist == self.line:
            self.follower = self.canvas.mpl_connect("motion_notify_event", self.followmouse)
            self.releaser = self.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", self.releaseonclick)
    def followmouse(self, event):
        if self.o == "h":
            self.line.set_ydata([event.ydata, event.ydata])
        else:
            self.line.set_xdata([event.xdata, event.xdata])
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
    def releaseonclick(self, event):
        if self.o == "h":
            self.Y = self.line.get_ydata()[0]
        else:
            self.X = self.line.get_xdata()[0]
        self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.releaser)
        self.canvas.mpl_disconnect(self.follower)
#
#fig = plt.figure()
#ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
#m = [2,5,7]
#n = [1,3,6]
#lineaa = []
#ax.set_xlim(0,10)
#for i,j in zip(n,m):
#    line = draggable_lines(ax, "h", i, j, 0.5,0.5)
#    lineaa.append(line)
#plt.show()
```

and this a sample code for PyQt mpl figure

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5 import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.lines as lines
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from Drag import draggable_lines

class Window(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    def __init__(self,):
        super().__init__()
        self.figure = Figure()
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Plot')
        self.button1.clicked.connect(self.plot)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
        btnlayout = QHBoxLayout()
        btnlayout.addWidget(self.button1)
        qw = QWidget(self)
        qw.setLayout(btnlayout)
        self.layout.addWidget(qw)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
    def plot(self):
        ax = self.figure.add_subplot(121)
        ax1 = self.figure.add_subplot(122)
        m = [2, 5, 7]
        n = [1, 3, 6]
        lineaa = []
        ax.set_xlim(0, 10)
        for i, j in zip(n, m):
            line = draggable_lines(ax, "h", i, j, 0.5, 0.5)
            lineaa.append(line)
        self.canvas.draw_idle()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Window()
    #main.setWindowTitle('Simple ')
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

i am not sure it is the different between canvas connecting to event in drag class file and the other in the main file
any advice will be appreciated

Comment: You would need to use `self.lineaa` instead of `lineaa`, else the list will be garbage collected as soon as the method returns.

Comment: thanks, for your time, and for saving mine, appreciated